# why my image (exported as sRGB, 8bit) looks color washed and pixeled after instagram upload

Tags: lightroom, post-processing, color-management, color-correction, adobe-camera-raw

I uploaded this images on Instagram using color space sRGB, 8 bit (as recommended) . Size: long edge: 2160 px.

The original images wasn't this color pixaleted (notice faint magenta bar running from tree to tower) as do the uploaded one in instagram. (changes marked in white circle)

Also, I am unable to see this prominent color boundary or bar formation (magenta to bluish shade) in my dell laptop screen in the original file, as visible over here in smartphone. Kindly, address this part as well. Also, could slight change in shadow area of color grading (lightroom classic) do this much banding (with 30% blending). I have no clue, this is the first time it's come to my notice, .

Could anyone shed some light.

[image: instagram image as saved in phone]

[image: original image]

Comment: One of the things you're trying to look at the picture on has poor [or no] profiling or colour repro. The pictures are to all intents & purposes identical [other than size], even if you overlay half of one on the other, there is no discernible difference on a colour-managed workspace - https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SSej.jpg The slight blue/red banding is there equally on both.

Comment: I don't know, if these images could be downloaded, if you enlarge it by as much as 25% difference in banding area is easily visible. Could you share, what do you mean by color profiling and how to ensure this doesn't happen in future work.

Comment: The files are both heavily compressed jpgs. There is very little detail in those colour bands & they do have pretty hard edges. Here I've blown up one segment, then heavily contrasted it to show how hard the edges actually are - https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQLQx.png

Comment: Could it be because of gradient filter to add haze to the atmosphere (dehaze slider to left, and blacks to right, minute exp increase ) above the top half, just among the band region. I used 38% featuring. Color grading was used with redish hue for shadows and highlights bluish.

Comment: The two pictures above are to all intents & purposes identical. Whatever caused it to collapse into "jpegness" was done before the versions we see above. If you have the higher res original, post that.

Comment: Hi Tetsujin, thanks for being patient with this amateur photographer. Here is the link to high resolution image of original. Also, please comment about banding, is this because of the reason I mentioned in previous comment.
https://imgur.com/gallery/zu8UETB

Comment: Looks like the damage was done at the original export to jpg, before you uploaded it to instagram [who will probably compress it again]. Testing by doing the same over-emphasis as before, your original looks like this [this is meant to make everything look worse to see what's going on] - https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJ53c.jpg - grainy but still quite 'smooth' in the transitions. Saving it out again as a smaller jpg at 50% quality, the same process gives this - https://i.stack.imgur.com/62cu4.jpg - & you can easily see the reasonably smooth transitions have now become very blocky.

Comment: Instagram says that for a horizontal image longest side should be max 1080px and I found 2160px  (double) is gonna be alright, (to compensate for the sharpness loss). Up until now, this formula worked,  or this blunder had not come to my notice. Either because the raw image has a single red-yellowish hue (due to very foggy morning) and I tried split toning to bring out the shadows (tree areas) more with reddish color and made highlights more bluish, it created this banding.

original Raw file: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TU5-mrlKCysoWJUxWLgzLdntYWxVs0ZP/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I don't know what more I can offer. Small, low qual jpgs will show banding & heavy pixellation. How bad that is depends on your screen calibration & how far it was compressed. trusting an online site to properly re-compress & resize is probably not the way to go about it. Send them what they want, don't let them change it..

Answer (score 1):

What you are probably seeing is the difference between how your display devices scale down the larger image and how they display the smaller image when you look at it on Instagram.

Viewed at the same size, there's no significant difference between the two images.

Comment: Lets forget about color pixel mess at the boundary of the band I tried looking at same scale in both laptop and mobile putting side by side. Samsung A71 shows this prominent banding while in laptop its not much noticeable. My question is, does it have to do with the numbers of color by dell (2014) laptop and my samaung A71(2020) can show.

Comment: @pixhibit.samco Has either device been calibrated and profiled? We can't see what you're seeing on your devices unless they've been brought as close as possible to the same (standardized) color response that properly calibrated and profiled devices are outputting. It could well be that the differences in your two displays are emphasizing the very subtle differences.

Answer (score 1):

Your two images look essentially identical. Here is a map of the difference once one is scaled to match the other:

[image: ![enter image description here]

The white is the pixels where the difference in level is 3 or more (difference along contrasting edges is due to rescaling).

As far as I can tell the purple bands are in both images, and it indeed looks like banding:

[image]

A smartphone is not a good instrument to judge the quality of a photo, the display is subject to a lot of processing whose only goal is to look better than the competition (more contrast and saturation, not more accuracy). By contrast your Dell will always look a bit bland, especially if equipped with a TN screen.

Comment: I have tried to look again at post processing job. I found that gradient filter that I used to add haze to the atmosphere (dehaze slider to left, and blacks to right, minute exp increase ) above the top half portion of the image, just above the band region, is the main culprit. More so because I applied luminance mask with 38 % smoothening, creating no-so -smooth fading. This in turn, allowed for clear pixel boundaries after Instagram compression.

Correct me if my analysis could be wrong?